# How to specify json format for Sinatra route with named parameter?

Tags: json, routes, sinatra

How do I add ".json" to a Sinatra route which includes a named parameter such as 
get '/view/:name'
?

I thought 
get '/view/:name.json'
might work but I get an "Unable to access path /view/name.json" exception.

Answer (score 1):

This code works perfectly:

```
get '/hello/:name.json' do
  "Hello #{params[:name]}"
end

=> /hello/samy.json outputs "Hello samy"
```

Please show the complete stack trace of your exception.

Comment: looks like this will only work if you place the route `get '/hello:name.json'` route above `get '/hello:name'`

Answer (score 0):

Also,

https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/issues/490